# c# - Converting dynamic into Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, lambda

Coding Platform: ASP.NET C# 4.0

I have the following snippet

```
public string PageID { get { return "20954654402"; } }
dynamic accounts = fb.Get("me/accounts");
if (accounts != null)
{
    bool isFound = false;
    foreach (dynamic account in accounts.data)
    {
        if (account.id == PageID)
        {
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isFound)
    {
        //  user not admin
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Two questions

1. <strike>Why does `(account.id == PageID)` errors (PageID is a string property)</strike>
   Update: That was a stupid unrelated error as I as calling all of these at PageMethods.
2. Is there a simpler and more C#4.0 like way to change the `foreach` loop?

Update:

Its the response from a call to Facebook API. A sample will be

```
{
    [{
        "name": "Codoons",
        "category": "Computers/technology",
        "id": "20954694402",
        "access_token": "179946368724329|-100002186424305|209546559074402|Hp6Ee-wFX9TEQ6AoEtng0D0my70"
    }, {
        "name": "Codtions Demo Application",
        "category": "Application",
        "id": "1799464329",
        "access_token": "179946368724329|-100002186424305|179946368724329|5KoXNOd7K9Ygdw7AMMEjE28_fAQ"
    }, {
        "name": "Naen's Demo Application",
        "category": "Application",
        "id": "192419846",
        "access_token": "179946368724329|61951d4bd5d346c6cefdd4c0.1-100002186424305|192328104139846|oS-ip8gd_1iEL9YR8khgrndIqQk"
    }]
}
```

Updated code also a little bit.

The intention is to get the `account.id` that matches with `PageID` and get the `access_token` associated with that `account.id`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What error does `account.id == PageID` cause?

Comment: 1. Try PageID.toString() 
2. for each seems fine, don't see a direct way to write it shorter

Comment: What type of object returns "fb.Get"?

Comment: @Matthias: `PageID` already is a `string`

Comment: but .id seems to be an integer, not?

Comment: code updated. hope its more clear now.

Comment: @naveen: Telling us, what the error is, will certainly help...!

Comment: @Daniel: I dunno who +1ed your answer. It wont work anyway.

Comment: @naveen: I can't follow you. Care to elaborate a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LINQ methods for an alternative to the foreach:

```
if(accounts.Any(a => a.id == PageID))
{
    //  user not admin
}
else
{

}
```

As to why it "errors": We can't say that, because we don't know what type `id` is of. But if `id` is of type `int`, this would explain an error.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. was busy else where. daniel your solution wont work. we are talking about dynamic types

Answer (score 0):

If the accounts collection can be modified (inserts, deletes) on another thread foreach will throw an exception when that happens (simple for loop won't).

Answer (score 0):

When using == with a string i.e. PageID is a string, then the account.id should also be a string, not an int or float, maybe thats whats causing the error

Answer (score 0):

```
accounts.data.Any(a => a.id.ToString() == PageID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dynamic predicate. Something like this:

```
var pagesWithId = (Predicate)((dynamic x) => x.id == PageId);
var pagesFound = accounts.FindAll(pagesWithId);

if(pagesFounds.Count() > 0)
 //do your thing
```